# Condional Branch QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to figure out how the Conditional Branch tool works. I looked at many cases from the Internet, but did not figure out how to solve my problem. For example, I made a simple model. I have a source layer with points, each of which has its own class, for example 1 or 2, it doesn't matter. I need the Conditional branch tool to split the model into two branches. The model should work in iteration mode, and in this mode, if the object has class 1, one branch works, if the class is 2, then another, in my test model these are two Buffer tools with different sizes for each class. I still do not understand how to correctly describe the conditions in the Conditional Branch[image]

Comment: Because your model, as you explained it, it is not a conditional branch.

Comment: hints: https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/advanced-qgis.html#using-conditions-in-modeler

Comment: @J. Monticolo
 Yes, I read it, but I didn't understand, can I use this tool in the way I described earlier?